# PHP/MySQL: What would cause a white page even though display PHP errors are turned on?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

You'll have to excuse my lack of details in regards to this question as I am still trying to work out what's going on.

I understand there may not be a straight answer to this but any help I can get will help me further debug the issue.

My issue is that all of a sudden my PHP script will exit and display a white page. No PHP or MySQL errors on the page and none in the error logs.

The issue occurs at very random times. When it does occur, it "appears" to be when there are a large number of MySQL queries are run at one time. When I say large, it might be a few hundred when sending out emails. Sometimes thousands, if a large import is occurring.

The last time this issue happened was last night when a user tried to send out 118 SMS Messages. After each SMS was queue and also stored in the archive, there would have been roughly a couple hundred queries.

I tried to replicate the issue today when trying to send 125 and 250 SMS Messages on two different occasions. Both worked fine. I then tried sending 250 SMS Messages and 250 emails and also worked fine.

I am using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk for my PHP pages and RDS for my MySQL database.

Does this sound like a PHP or MySQL issue? And if neither are giving me anything in the error logs, do you have any suggestions as to what I can do to further debug this? Are there some other hidden logs or logging I should turn on?

Or is there any MySQL or PHP settings I should look at to try get around the issue?

Comment: the list of possibilities approaches the infinite

Comment: You don't you check error log?

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 60); //300 seconds = 5 minutes try to add in php file may it will display what kind of error is there

Answer (score 1):

Configuration side:

First, look into the server's error log (it is different from PHP error log). For example, apache has its own log files, related to the startup of different modules/server messages and etc. PHP's error log is a separate log, so if there are no messages there - it doesn't mean anything.

Second, look into php.ini and see your log settings - which level of errors are written.

Program side:

First, split your code, so that it processes a maximum of 50 records per run. Redo your scripts so that it runs and re-runs until executes all necessary actions.

Second, look into time/memory limits - are they sufficient to execute your operations? Say, sending mail takes 1 second, if your time limit is 30 seconds - you can only send a maximum of 30 emails. It is related to the first part, since you want to partition your tasks into segments which can be safely executed within the provided limits.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone, the issue ending up being my DNS provider (Route S3). Even though I had increased my time limit on my PHP (max_execution_time), my DNS provider had a time limit of 60 seconds. So as soon as the 60 seconds ticked past, it killed it. That's why I didn't get any errors.

I've increased this limit but will also be relooking at my code :)